Why is address of array-typed variable different when it is local vs when it is a function argument?
We are taught from an early age that the name of an array-typed variable yields the address of it's zeroth element, and that taking the address of that name yields the same address, but with a different pointer type (the type of the whole array rather than the type of a single element). However, this is not true if the array-typed variable is a function argument. In this case "&" yields the address on the stack when the address of the passed-in array is stored, as if the argument was declared "X* x" rather than "X x[]". Why is this?
I know enough to understand that arrays are not passed by copying, they are passed by sending the address of the zeroth element. My code shows this, so please do not tell me. My question is, why wasn't the & operator ignored when it was applied to the array-typed function argument?
Program:
#include <stdio.h>

void myfunc(int arg_ia[3])
{
    int loc_ia[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };

    printf("loc_ia = %p, &loc_ia[0] = %p, &loc_ia = %p, loc_ia==&loc_ia[0] = %d, loc_ia==&loc_ia = %d\n",
           loc_ia, &loc_ia[0], &loc_ia, (void*)loc_ia == (void*)&loc_ia[0],  (void*)loc_ia == (void*)&loc_ia);

    printf("arg_ia = %p, &arg_ia[0] = %p, &arg_ia = %p, arg_ia==&arg_ia[0] = %d, arg_ia==&arg_ia = %d\n",
           arg_ia, &arg_ia[0], &arg_ia, (void*)arg_ia == (void*)&arg_ia[0], (void*)arg_ia == (void*)&arg_ia);    
}

int main(void)
{
    int mai_ia[3] = { 4, 5, 6 };

    printf("mai_ia = %p, &mai_ia[0] = %p, &mai_ia = %p, mai_ia==&mai_ia[0] = %d, mai_ia==&mai_ia = %d\n",
           mai_ia, &mai_ia[0], &mai_ia, (void*)mai_ia == (void*)&mai_ia[0], (void*)mai_ia == (void*)&mai_ia);    

    myfunc(mai_ia);
}

Output:
mai_ia = 0x7ff7b45195bc, &mai_ia[0] = 0x7ff7b45195bc, &mai_ia = 0x7ff7b45195bc, mai_ia==&mai_ia[0] = 1, mai_ia==&mai_ia = 1
loc_ia = 0x7ff7b451958c, &loc_ia[0] = 0x7ff7b451958c, &loc_ia = 0x7ff7b451958c, loc_ia==&loc_ia[0] = 1, loc_ia==&loc_ia = 1
arg_ia = 0x7ff7b45195bc, &arg_ia[0] = 0x7ff7b45195bc, &arg_ia = 0x7ff7b4519580, arg_ia==&arg_ia[0] = 1, arg_ia==&arg_ia = 0

Thank you.

A function argument is not an array, it's a pointer. &arg_Ia is the address of the pointer, not the address of the array it points to.

int arg_ia[3] is actually treated as int *arg_ia

"We are taught from an early age that the name of an array-typed variable yields the address of it's zeroth element" - With less drama: When passed as an argument to functions an array decays into a pointer to its first element.

Please read the question carefully. I am not asking what gets put onto the stack when the function is called. This is the address of the zeroth element of the array. The question is why does the address-of operator behave different when applied to a value which is declared with array syntax. Why does &arg_ia yield an address on the local call stack and not the base address that was passed in?

Put simply, arrays cannot be parameters to a function.
Any function defined as taking an array as a parameter is in fact taking a pointer instead.  Section 6.7.6.3p7 of the C standard states the following regarding function parameters:

A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of type’’ shall be adjusted to
‘‘qualified pointer to type’’, where the type qualifiers (if any) are
those specified within the [ and ] of the array type derivation. If
the keyword static also appears within the [ and ] of the array type
derivation, then for each call to the function, the value of the
corresponding actual argument shall provide access to the first
element of an array with at least as many elements as specified by the
size expression

This means that your function declared like this:
void myfunc(int arg_ia[3]) {

Is exactly equivalent to:
void myfunc(int *arg_ia) {

So when you call the function like this:
myfunc(mai_ia);

It received the address of the first element of the array.
You could in fact change the function to take the array's address:
void myfunc(int (arg_ia*)[3]) {

Which can be called like this:
myfunc(&mai_ia);

In which case the value of arg_ia in the function will be the address of the array mai_ia in main (which is the same as the address of its first element).

My question does not ask what value is passed to the function. I know this is the base address of the array. My question is why does &arg_ia not yield that base address when it does for other symbols declared with array syntax. You have hinted at the answer by saying the declaration is adjusted to a pointer type, but you have muddied it by including extraneous information.

A parameter declared as “int * arg_ia” is not EXACTLY equivalent to “int arg_ia[]” because the latter precludes assignment to the symbol viz “arg_ia = &(some other int)”. For that equivalence you need “int * const arg_ia”.

@kbro You have it backwards.  A parameter declared as int arg_ia[] is exactly the same as int *arg_ia, not the other way around.

It is not EXACTLY the same.  You can assign a value to a symbol whose type is pointer-to-T.  You cannot assign a value to a symbol whose type is array-of-T.
int i = 1; int * ip = &i; /* good */ int ia[1]; ia = &i; /* illegal */ 

@kbro I didn't say that an array is exactly the same as a pointer.  I said a parameter declared as an array is exactly the same as a parameter declared as a pointer.

Apologies!  I added arg_ia = loc_ia; to my test function, and the code compiled and did exactly that!!  So you CAN assign a value to a symbol declared with array-typed syntax. K&R really did a thorough job of it when they dreamt up that feature, didn't they! Fortunately loc_ia = arg_ia; still throws a compiler error, so the world has not gone completely mad.

@dbush has provided the correct answer, but obscured it with unnecessary commentary about how arrays are passed into functions - I already said I know that. Here is an answer which focuses on the specific question - "why does address-of behave differently?"
The answer (in section 6.7.6.3p7 of the C standard, as noted by @dbush) is that the compiler SILENTLY ALTERS the type of the parameter from int[] to int*, so the address-of operator acts on a POINTER variable (which has an actual address) rather than an ARRAY variable (which does not).  This can be seen in my modified example, which also shows that an array-typed variable can be passed identically to both an array-typed and a pointer-typed function parameter, just to underscore that I really do know.
Program:
#include <stdio.h>

void myfunc(int arg_ia[3], int * arg_ip)
{
    int loc_ia[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };

    printf("loc_ia = %p, &loc_ia[0] = %p, &loc_ia = %p, loc_ia==&loc_ia[0] = %d, loc_ia==&loc_ia = %d\n",
           loc_ia, &loc_ia[0], &loc_ia, (void*)loc_ia == (void*)&loc_ia[0],  (void*)loc_ia == (void*)&loc_ia);

    printf("arg_ia = %p, &arg_ia[0] = %p, &arg_ia = %p, arg_ia==&arg_ia[0] = %d, arg_ia==&arg_ia = %d\n",
           arg_ia, &arg_ia[0], &arg_ia, (void*)arg_ia == (void*)&arg_ia[0], (void*)arg_ia == (void*)&arg_ia);    

    printf("arg_ip = %p, &arg_ip[0] = %p, &arg_ip = %p, arg_ip==&arg_ip[0] = %d, arg_ip==&arg_ip = %d\n",
           arg_ip, &arg_ip[0], &arg_ip, (void*)arg_ip == (void*)&arg_ip[0], (void*)arg_ip == (void*)&arg_ip);    
        
}

int main(void)
{
    int mai_ia[3] = { 4, 5, 6 };

    printf("mai_ia = %p, &mai_ia[0] = %p, &mai_ia = %p, mai_ia==&mai_ia[0] = %d, mai_ia==&mai_ia = %d\n",
           mai_ia, &mai_ia[0], &mai_ia, (void*)mai_ia == (void*)&mai_ia[0], (void*)mai_ia == (void*)&mai_ia);    

    myfunc(mai_ia, mai_ia);
}

Output:
mai_ia = 0x30da9f83c, &mai_ia[0] = 0x30da9f83c, &mai_ia = 0x30da9f83c, mai_ia==&mai_ia[0] = 1, mai_ia==&mai_ia = 1
loc_ia = 0x30da9f80c, &loc_ia[0] = 0x30da9f80c, &loc_ia = 0x30da9f80c, loc_ia==&loc_ia[0] = 1, loc_ia==&loc_ia = 1
arg_ia = 0x30da9f83c, &arg_ia[0] = 0x30da9f83c, &arg_ia = 0x30da9f800, arg_ia==&arg_ia[0] = 1, arg_ia==&arg_ia = 0
arg_ip = 0x30da9f83c, &arg_ip[0] = 0x30da9f83c, &arg_ip = 0x30da9f7f8, arg_ip==&arg_ip[0] = 1, arg_ip==&arg_ip = 0


Detail: "an array-typed variable can be passed ..." --> An array is converted to the address of the first element before being passed, so the function is not receiving an array argument, but a pointer one.  Much like printf("%g", 1.23f); where the float is converted to a double before being passed to the function, a ... argument is never float and a function argument is never an array.

@chux-ReinstateMonica this has nothing to do with how the value is passed into the function. Is it entirely down to how the compiler applies the address-of operator to the parameter INSIDE the function.

Referring to my venerable 1988 Second Edition K&R (which replace the 1978 First Edition I used at university from a very early age)...
"Within the called function, this argument is a local variable, and so an array name parameter is a pointer, that is, a variable containing an address."
Obviously I don't absorb the full ramifications of that back in my university days, always assuming that the First Edition said it at all!





The question is why does the address-of operator behave different when applied to a value which is declared with array syntax (?) Ref

The result of the address operator & does not depend on the value of the object, only on the address of the object.
With the below code:
&loc_ia is the address of loc_ia.  loc_ia is an array.
&arg_ia is the address of arg_ia.  arg_ia is an pointer.
void myfunc(int arg_ia[3]) {
    int loc_ia[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };

    printf("loc_ia = %p, &loc_ia[0] = %p, &loc_ia = %p\n",
           loc_ia, &loc_ia[0], &loc_ia);

    printf("arg_ia = %p, &arg_ia[0] = %p, &arg_ia = %p\n",
           arg_ia, &arg_ia[0], &arg_ia);    

    // Pedantic: %p matches a void *, so code really should be
    printf("loc_ia = %p, &loc_ia[0] = %p, &loc_ia = %p\n",
           (void *) loc_ia, (void *) &loc_ia[0], (void *) &loc_ia);
    // etc.
}



Why does &arg_ia yield an address on the local call stack and not the base address that was passed in?

The "base address" of what was passed in is the value of the pointer arg_ia.  The & operator depends on the address of the object, a pointer in this case, not its value. Thus a local call stack address is expected.

you haven't explained WHY arg_ia is a pointer when clearly it is declared with array syntax.  What sneaky section of the C standard mandates this re-interpretation?

@kbro "What sneaky section of the C standard mandates this re-interpretation?" --> C23dr  6.7.6.3 6 "A declaration of a parameter as "array of type" shall be adjusted to "qualified pointer to type", where the type qualifiers (if any) are those specified within the [ and ] of the array type derivation. If the keyword static also appears within the [ and ] of the array type derivation, then for each call to the function, the value of the corresponding actual argument shall provide access to the first element of an array with at least as many elements as specified by the size expression."

Finally, a comment that answers the question.
